# Join returns 10000 rows, not 1

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand why one of these three SQL queries costs a lot more than the other two.

I have a table prices(Security int,Date datetime,Price money) with primary key Security,Date. Security is a foreign key to the securities table (ID int,Security nvarchar,...... ) with primary key ID, and non-clustered index on Security (the name of the security).

I want to find the price nearest to the date '20171002' for the security with ID=75 (Security name 'USD'). Query 3 takes about 5 times longer than the other two.

First query:

```
select p.price from prices p
where p.Security=75
and Date=
(
select MAX(date) from prices 
where Security=p.Security
and Date<='20171002'
)
```

Second query:

```
declare @t int
set @t=(select ID from Securities where Security='USD')

select p.price from prices p
where p.Security=@t
and Date=
(
select MAX(date) from prices 
where Security=p.Security
and Date<='20171002'
)
```

Third query:

```
select p.price from prices p
inner join Securities s on s.ID=p.Security
where s.Security='USD'
and Date=
(
select MAX(date) from prices 
where Security=p.Security
and Date<='20171002'
)
```

[Execution Plan for third query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZzjJ.jpg)

[Clustered Index Seek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4DjJ.jpg)

The third query reads all rows in the prices table for security 75 (USD) with dates before '20171002' (10000 rows). The other two just read the top row <= '20171002' which they get to directly with the primary key (ID,Date) on the prices table.

If I want to explicitly join to the securities table to retrieve the price from the securities name rather than directly from the security's ID, is there a different way to write the query so only the top row before '20171002' is read?

Comment: `SELECT TOP (1) p.Price ..... ORDER BY Date DESC` ?

Comment: Yes, top(1) is much better than the third query, only reading one row. It's still double the cost of queries 1 and 2. But why can't the query analyzer use a similar plan to what it used for top(1) when max(date) is used?

Comment: What does the Execution Plan for the 3rd query look like?

Comment: How do I include the Execution Plan? Just do a screen dump then load the image? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I've added a screen dump of the 3rd query